# Linq2Sql strange behaviour

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

in my DB, I have e.g. 13 orders.

The code below returns all of them, if the `OrderID = 0` and `CustomerName = "lorem"`.

If I comment the line `(OrderID == 0) ?....` it works fine. What's wrong ?

```
var result = (from x in db.Order
              where
                  (OrderID == 0) ? x.OrderID > 0 : x.OrderID == OrderID
                  &&
                  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerName)) ? 
                                            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerName)
                                            :
                                            x.User.Name.Contains(CustomerName)
              select x)
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can not define conditional condition inside LINQ query in this way, what you *can* do is, for example:

```
var result = (from x in db.Order where
              ((OrderID == 0 && x.OrderID > 0) ||  
                (OrderID != 0 && x.OrderID == OrderID))
                  &&
                  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerName)) ? 
                                            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerName)
                                            :
                                            x.User.Name.Contains(CustomerName)....
```

Comment: You've got it. The C# ternary operator would have been evaluated only once and the condition applied that way through all the records.

Comment: Your code works fine. But I'm wondering why my code have returned all rows ?